# How to persist inputs in the Unity InputSystem

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to execute a roll while the player is moving and have them continue to move in that direction as long as they hold down the movement key. However, since the Action function of Unity's InputSystem is called when the InputValue changes, there is a problem with holding down the key before rolling, which prevents the Action function from being called.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Will : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum WillState
    {
        IDLE,
        RUN,
        ROLL
    }

    private Rigidbody2D _rigid;
    private Animator _anim;

    public WillState _currentState;
    public Vector2 _moveInput;
    public float Horizontal { get; private set; }
    public float Vertical { get; private set; }

    private float _moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    private float _rollDistance = 1.4f;

    public bool _canMove = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case WillState.IDLE:
                _anim.Play("Idle");
                break;
            case WillState.RUN:
                _anim.SetFloat("MoveX", _moveInput.x);
                _anim.SetFloat("MoveY", _moveInput.y);
                _anim.Play("Run");
                break;
            case WillState.ROLL:
                _anim.Play("Roll");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case WillState.IDLE:
                break;
            case WillState.RUN:
                _rigid.MovePosition(_rigid.position + _moveInput * _moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                break;
            case WillState.ROLL:
                _rigid.MovePosition(_rigid.position + _moveInput * _rollDistance * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        if (_canMove)
        {
            _moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
            if (_moveInput != Vector2.zero)
            {
                ChangeState(WillState.RUN);
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeState(WillState.IDLE);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnRoll()
    {
        _canMove = false;
        ChangeState(WillState.ROLL);
    }

    void RollFinished()
    {
        _canMove = true;
        ChangeState(WillState.IDLE);
    }

    void ChangeState(WillState newState)
    {
        _currentState = newState;
    }

}
```

The RollFinished function is for calling an event function at the end of the Roll animation. After rolling, the player becomes idle and must be rekeyed to move. I want to call the OnMove function after rolling, even if I'm still inputting before rolling.

I've watched a lot of videos and manuals on Unity InputSystem, but I can't come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not Unity Input System, but your code logic is the problem. You code ignores input during roll in OnMove function. So maybe something like this:

```
    void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        _moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
        TryMove();
    }
    
    private void TryMove()
    {
        if (_canMove)
        {
            if (_moveInput != Vector2.zero)
            {
                ChangeState(WillState.RUN);
            }
            else
            {
                ChangeState(WillState.IDLE);
            }
        }
    }

    void RollFinished()
    {
        _canMove = true;
        TryMove();
    }
```